# Triggering a component dialog

Tags: vuejs2, element-ui

I'm attempting to learn VueJS and ElementUI to port over a legacy app. I'm very new to VueJS and am trying to get to grips with the basics. Understanding reusable components is going to be key for me, so I'm trying to get an example dialog working. Can someone help me work out why the dialog won't display when I click on the  button on my Test page. I've registered the component but am unsure how I trigger it. The sample code is based on a tutorial for components I've found and ElementUI form example.

Test.vue

```
<template>
  <el-button
    type="success"
    @click="dialogFormVisible = true"
    size="small"
    icon="el-icon-plus"
    >click to open the Dialog</el-button>
  
    <Dialog v-model="dialogFormVisible" />
  
</template>

 <script>
 import Dialog from "@/components/CustomerForm.vue";

 export default {
  name: "App",
  components: { Dialog },
  data() {
    return {
      dialogFormVisible: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log("confirm");
      this.dialogFormVisible = false;
    },
  },
 };
</script>
```

CustomerForm.vue

```
<template>
  <el-dialog title="Customer Name" v-model="dialogFormVisible">
    <el-form :model="form">
      <el-form-item label="Activity name">
        <el-input v-model="form.name"></el-input>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Activity zone">
        <el-select v-model="form.region" placeholder="please select your zone">
          <el-option label="Zone one" value="shanghai"></el-option>
          <el-option label="Zone two" value="beijing"></el-option>
        </el-select>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item label="Activity time">
        <el-col :span="11">
          <el-date-picker
            type="date"
            placeholder="Pick a date"
            v-model="form.date1"
            style="width: 100%"
          ></el-date-picker>
        </el-col>
        <el-col class="line" :span="2">-</el-col>
        <el-col :span="11">
          <el-time-picker
            placeholder="Pick a time"
            v-model="form.date2"
            style="width: 100%"
          ></el-time-picker>
        </el-col>
      </el-form-item>
      <el-form-item>
        <el-button type="primary" @click="submit">Create</el-button>
        <el-button>Cancel</el-button>
      </el-form-item>
    </el-form>
  </el-dialog>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      dialogFormVisible: false,
      form: {
        name: "",
        region: "",
        date1: "",
        date2: "",
      },
      formLabelWidth: "120px",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log("submit!");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: el-button is a custom component as such it will only listen to the 'click' event if there is an associated 'emit' from the component. if you want to listen to it natively you need to use '.native' to the click => `v-on:click.native="submit"'

Comment: i believe vue 3 removes `.native` event modifier
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code so it now triggers the dialog. However, the dialog is empty and doesn't display the contents of CustomerForm.

Comment: change `<el-dialog title="Customer Name" v-model="dialogFormVisible">` to a `v-if` or `v-show`

Comment: click i would do `dialogFormVisible = !dialogFormVisible` -> acts as a toggle instead of just an open button